# python - capture pandoc error message via subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, pandoc

I am writing some Python code that interacts with `pandoc` via the `subprocess` module. I am, however, having trouble capturing what `pandoc` would normally print to the console whenever a command goes wrong. For example, I put this command into Terminal:

```
pandoc -N  --variable mainfont=Georgia --variable sansfont=Arial --variable monofont="Bitstream Vera Sans Mono" --variable fontsize=12pt --variable version=1.10 README.txt  --latex-engine=xelatex --toc -o README.pdf
```

And `pandoc` then spits out this error message:

```
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"
! 
! The font "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono" cannot be found.
! 
! See the fontspec documentation for further information.
! 
! For immediate help type H .
!...............................................                                                   
l.20 ...apping=tex-ansi]{Bitstream Vera Sans Mono}  
pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
```

Now, I've tried to capture this same error message within my Python code, but to no avail. My current code looks like this:

```
cmd = ['pandoc', '-N', '--variable=mainfont:Georgia', '--variable=sansfont:Arial', '--variable=monofont:"Bitstream Vera Sans Mono"', '--variable=fontsize:12pt', '--variable=version:1.10', 'README.txt', '--latex-engine=xelatex', '--toc', '--output=README.pdf']
proc = subprocess.check_output(cmd, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print proc
```

But this only tells me that the command `returned non-zero exit status 43`. It doesn't print the full (actually informative) error message that I get in the console.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), it looks like something like this should work.

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output(cmd)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print e.output
```

Comment: Thanks @g-poore. I edited your answer to define CalledProcessError, but otherwise it works. I knew the answer would be relatively simple and make me feel somewhat foolish for failing to find it.

Comment: @smargh: another alternative is to call `subprocess.Popen` directly and collect the output using `Popen.communicate()` method that doesn't raise an exception if Popen.returncode is not `0`.